# SwipeRefreshLayout height is always 0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-framelayout, swiperefreshlayout

I have a fragment with a SwipeRefreshLayout and will be added inside a FrameLayout in the activity on run time.

The problem is that SwipeRefreshLayout height is always 0 whatever the height parameter value is (wrap_content or match_parent).

Here is my fragment code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/expensesLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/expenses_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/recycler_view_padding_bottom"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_item_margin" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And here is my activity code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:context=".expenses.ExpensesActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dr_nav_header"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/title_margin_bottom"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedTitle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout //Inside this frame my fragment will be added
            android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_expense"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/controllers_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: "SwipeRefreshLayout height is always 0" - How are you determining that, exactly?

Comment: When I fix the height to 200 dp (for example) it will be shown!

Comment: Possibly it's "fighting" with the extraneous `ViewGroup`s you have there. You don't need the `NestedScrollView` around the `FrameLayout`, since `RecyclerView`s scroll on their own, and the `LinearLayout` around the `RecyclerView` isn't really necessary, unless you're putting something else in there.

Comment: The problem is that if I removed the NestedScrollView then the Framelayout will flow over the AppBarLayout and will not be appended after it. Knowing that I am implementing a collapsible tool bar. Also I tried to remove the LinearLayout but no success.

Comment: Thank you Mike M. for the hint "fighting"

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved, I just removed the NestedScrollView and I gave its behavior to the FrameLayout.